# Infinitiv und Vergangenheitsform

Tags: infinitive

Kann man den folgenden Satz irgendwie in der Vergangenheitsform ausdrücken?

> Ich schäme mich dafür, ein schlechter Mensch sein zu wollen.

Das Folgende ist ja sicherlich falsch (oder etwa nicht)?

> Ich schäme mich dafür, früher ein schlechter Mensch sein zu wollen.

Wie wäre es denn mit:

> Ich schäme mich dafür, früher ein schlechter Mensch zu sein gewollt habe.

Würde hier auch alternativ der folgende Satz richtig sein?

> Ich schäme mich dafür, früher ein schlechter Mensch gewollt zu sein habe.

Answer (score 2):

Du hast es fast.

Um zu einer Lösung zu kommen, hilft es, die Sache zu vereinfachen und die Komplexität schrittweise zu erhöhen:

> Ich schäme mich dafür, [etwas] gewollt zu haben.

> Ich schäme mich dafür, ein schlechter Mensch zu sein gewollt zu haben.

("Was habe ich gewollt?" - *ein schlechter Mensch zu sein*)

Alternativ:

> Ich schäme mich dafür, dass ich [etwas] gewollt habe.

> Ich schäme mich dafür, dass ich ein schlechter Mensch zu sein gewollt habe.

Etwas stilsicherer:

> Ich schäme mich dafür, dass ich gewollt habe, ein schlechter Mensch zu sein.

Comment: Korrekte Grammatik, aber auch das letzte Beispiel ist immer noch sehr verschwurbelt. Siehe die Antwort von user unknown.

Comment: @Roland Stimmt.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich schäme mich dafür, dass ich früher ein schlechter Mensch sein wollte.

Answer (score 0):

Deine Versuche sind leider alle ungültig, wobei ich erst gar nicht erst versuchen würde, den Satz in die Vergangenheitsform zu übertragen, das Ergebnis wäre mir zu sperrig. Etwas einfacher ist

> Ich schäme mich für meinen früheren Wunsch, ein schlechter Mensch zu sein.

als eine dieser Alternativen:

> Ich schäme mich für meinen früheren/damaligen Wunsch/Willen, ein schlechter Mensch zu sein.